# Converting series dictionary from a dataframe column to separate columns in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

```
I have this dataframe(df) that looks like this
`
user_id |date       |last_dep_amt| dep_amt| Bin       | Action    
1031    |2017-03-11 |200.0       |100     | 100-200   | [{'A1':[350,400,450],
                                                          'A2':[450,480,490],
                                                          'A3':[500,550,600],
                                                          'A4':[650, 700,850],
                                                          'A5':[750,800,950],
                                                       'Last_5_deposits':[50],
                                                       'num_unique_a1':3,
                                                       'num_unique_a2':4,
                                                       'num_unique_a3':7,
                                                       'num_unique_a4':8,
                                                       'num_unique_a5':9}]
1031    |2017-03-12 |300.0       |120     | 100-200   | [{'A1':[250,300,550],
                                                          'A2':[150,440,460],
                                                          'A3':[250,300,430],
                                                          'A4':[350, 500,650],
                                                          'A5':[650,700,780],
                                                       'Last_5_deposits':[50],
                                                       'num_unique_a1':3,
                                                       'num_unique_a2':4,
                                                       'num_unique_a3':7,
                                                       'num_unique_a4':8,
                                                       'num_unique_a5':9}]
231 |2017-03-14 |350.0       |130     | 100-200   | [{'A1':[250,300,550],
                                                          'A2':[150,440,460],
                                                          'A3':[250,300,430],
                                                          'A4':[350, 500,650],
                                                          'A5':[650,700,780],
                                                       'Last_5_deposits':[50],
                                                       'num_unique_a1':3,
                                                       'num_unique_a2':4,
                                                       'num_unique_a3':7,
                                                       'num_unique_a4':8,
                                                       'num_unique_a5':9}]
`      
Essentially containing 6 columns. Where the last column('Action') of the dataframe is list of dictionary.
```

So i need to split the last column('Action') into multiple columns like below
for ex:
user_id|date|last_dep_amt| dep_amt|Bin|A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|Last_5_deposits|
num_unique_a1|num_unique_a2|num_unique_a3|num_unique_a4|num_unique_a5

Little about the dataframe
`type(df['Action']) - pandas.core.series.Series`
`type(df)  - pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

Expected output: All the sub columns under the Action column have to be split into separate columns

    `user_id|date|last_dep_amt|dep_amt|Bin|A1|A2|A3|A4|A5|Last_5_deposits|
    num_unique_a1|num_unique_a2|num_unique_a3|num_unique_a4|num_unique_a5`

    `

```
  +---------+-----------+--------------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
    | user_id |   date    | last_dep_amt | dep_amt |   Bin   |      A1       |      A2       |      A3       |       A4       |      A5       | Last_5_deposits | num_unique_a1 | num_unique_a2 | num_unique_a3 |  num_unique_a4 | num_unique_a5  |
    +---------+-----------+--------------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
    |    1031 | 3/11/2017 |          200 |     100 | 100-200 | [350,400,450] | [450,480,490] | [500,550,600] | [650, 700,850] | [750,800,950] | [50]            |             3 |             4 |             7 |              8 |              9 |
    +---------+-----------+--------------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+

`
Also have attached below the link that contains an image of the expected final output needed from the above dataframe(df)
`
<https://ibb.co/0JyKhHQ>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df_action=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(key) for key in df['Action']]).reset_index(drop=True)
new_df=pd.concat([df[['user_id','date','last_dep_amt','dep_amt','Bin']],df_action],axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

---

**Output:**

```
   user_id        date  last_dep_amt  dep_amt      Bin               A1  \
0     1031  2017-03-11         200.0      100  100-200  [350, 400, 450]   
1     1031  2017-03-12         300.0      120  100-200  [250, 300, 550]   
2      231  2017-03-14         350.0      130  100-200  [250, 300, 550]   

                A2               A3               A4               A5  \
0  [450, 480, 490]  [500, 550, 600]  [650, 700, 850]  [750, 800, 950]   
1  [150, 440, 460]  [250, 300, 430]  [350, 500, 650]  [650, 700, 780]   
2  [150, 440, 460]  [250, 300, 430]  [350, 500, 650]  [650, 700, 780]   

  Last_5_deposits  num_unique_a1  num_unique_a2  num_unique_a3  num_unique_a4  \
0            [50]              3              4              7              8   
1            [50]              3              4              7              8   
2            [50]              3              4              7              8   

   num_unique_a5  
0              9  
1              9  
2              9
```

Comment: `@ansev` I tried your code the first line`f_action=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(key) for key in df['Action']]).reset_index(drop=True)` gave me the following error : `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`
So i tried this as well : `df_action=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(columns=['key']) for key in ab2['Action']]).reset_index(drop=True)`.
This worked but on executing `print(new_df)` gave me old columns such as userid,date,last_dep_amt,dep_amt,bin and new column "key" where the values under this "key" column were all `NaN` row values.